# Why this print statement changes the previous pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, printf

here is the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
  int * i;
  int * j;
  printf("%d\n", i);
  printf("%d\n", j);
}
```

I compiled and ran it, and the output was:

```
888086464
0
```

However, if I comment out the second printf

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
  int * i;
  int * j;
  printf("%d\n", i);
  //printf("%d\n", j);
}
```

The out put beomes:

```
0
```

I'm wondering why the second printf changes the pointer i.
And, how does C initalize pointers? As far as I know, if a pointer is not initialized, it would have value Null which is equal to 0, correct? Why in the first output, the i was initialized?

EDIT: Following the suggestions from you guys, I made some changes:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
  int * i;
  int * j;
  printf("%p\n", i);
  printf("%p\n", j);
}
```

which gives

```
0x7fff67a361b0
(nil)
```

But when I comment out the second printf

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
  int * i;
  int * j;
  printf("%p\n", i);
  //printf("%p\n", j);
}
```

The output is nil.
I'm curious why in the first version with two printf, only the j is nil while i is not.

Comment: Besides using uninitialized data (which is undefined), you are passing pointers to `printf()` with the `%d` format, which is undefined too. You would be better off using `%p` or explicitly converting from pointer to `int`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could answer your question by looking at the generated machine code for the two versions (for gcc, that should be the -S option).

I *suspect* that in the second version, `j` isn't being created at all (since it isn't being used anywhere), so `i` is being created in the slot that would have been used for `j`.  For whatever reason, your stack is set up so that the top 64 bits are `0x0000000000000000`followed by `0x00007fff67a361b0`

IOW, in the first version, your stack looks like

```
 Item        Address            00  01  02  03  04  05  06  07   
 ----        -------            --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --
    j        0x8000             00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00
    i        0x8008             00  00  7f  ff  67  a3  61  b0
```

whereas in the second version, it looks like

```
 Item        Address            00  01  02  03  04  05  06  07   
 ----        -------            --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --
    i        0x8000             00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00
             0x8008             ??  ??  ??  ??  ??  ??  ??  ??
```

(address values are only for illustration, and do not correspond to any real architecture).

For giggles, modify the print statements to be

```
printf("%p: %p\n", &i, i);
printf("%p: %p\n", &j, j);
```

in the first version and

```
printf("%p: %p\n", &i, i);
```

in the second.  I will bet money that the value printed for `&i` (the address of the variable `i`) in the second version will be the same as the value printed for `&j` (the address of the variable `j`) in the first version.

**NOTE** - this has nothing to do with the C *language*, and everything to do with your specific implementation (compiler, linker, etc.).  I'm not convinced you are invoking undefined behavior (you aren't accessing any memory through those invalid pointers), but you are seeing the perils of not explicitly initializing pointer values.

Variables declared at block scope without the `static` keyword are not initialized; whatever is in memory at the time the variable is instantiated is what the initial value is, and that bit pattern may not represent a valid value for that type (this is called a *trap representation*).  Variables declared at file scope (outside of any function) or with the `static` keyword are initialized to 0 or NULL, depending on whether it's a scalar or pointer type.  The rules are a little more complicated for aggregate types (arrays, structs, and unions), but the basic principle is the same.

Comment: That is exactly the explanation I'm looking for, thank you very much!

Comment: I just realized that there's no reason for the stack to be the same between the two runs, apart from the first element being all 0.  You might want to run a debugger to examine the stack for the two versions.  But again, this is all about *your specific implementation*, not C in general.  There's no guarantee that the same code would behave the same way with a different compiler.

Answer (score 4):

You don't initialize either of your pointers. What you are looking at is undefined behavior. The values you see are just garbage values from your stack, which could change each time you run it.

Comment: Why i points to a garbage value, and j does not? in the first output.

Comment: They're both garbage values. Just because one of them happens to be `0` doesn't mean it's not still garbage.

Comment: But each time I run it, the second would always be 0. I don't think it's a coincidence, is it?

Comment: @octref It is absolutely a coincidence. It just happens that you're not running anything else, so the stack always ends up looking the same when you initialize those variables. If you try doing some other stuff (like running other functions beforehand) then their values will probably change.

Comment: @octref: No, it is not a mere coincidence, but it is behavior caused by aspects of your computing environment other than the C standard. In particular, you are not controlling those aspects, so you cannot rely on there always being a zero there. With sufficient investigation, you might find out why there is a zero there, possibly as some consequence of the code that initializes the environment in preparation for starting a C program. But the answer will not be in C semantics.

Comment: @EricPostpischil : Good point. I don't believe it's a coincidence, but I accept the view that this might not be a expectable behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

If you did not initialized pointer it can have any value.

You **must** initialize them. Otherwise you will get an `undefined behavior`.

Also the the correct way of the pointers printing is:

```
printf("%p", pointer);
```

Answer (score 0):

"Not initialized" is very different than "initialized to 0" (or NULL).

The variables `i` and `j` are not initialized. They are left with what the memory has in it.

When you comment out the second `printf`, variable `j` is not used anymore. It is probably optimized out by the compiler (meaning not defined at all). In such a case, `i` may be at a different location, having a different *uninitialized* value.

This is actually *undefined behavior*. My last section is pure speculation, you can never be sure.

Comment: But with two printf, where i and j are both used, why would one be nil and one has an address?

Answer (score 0):

The pointers could hold anything. C doesn't initialise local (automatic) variables, unless you tell it to. If you define them as static, they're initialised with NULL.

Also you should use `%p` to print pointers, not `%d`.

Answer (score 0):

you will get **undefined behaviour** if you do not initialize the pointer address

here you are printing the pointer address as int and this is not correct you should use `"%p"`  instead of `"%d"`

Comment: `%u` and `%x` expect an `unsigned int` and are just as wrong as `%d`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Accessing indeterminate memory causes undefined behavior in C90, and is treated as undefined behaviors by modern compilers regardless of the exact wording of more recent standards. http://kqueue.org/blog/2012/06/25/more-randomness-or-less/

Comment: @EricPostpischil (1) 1.6 DEFINITIONS OF TERMS […] Undefined behavior --- behavior, upon use of a nonportable or erroneous program construct, of erroneous data, or of indeterminately-valued objects, […]

Comment: @EricPostpischil If you are interested in the story of the sentence “could have been declared with the register storage class”, the defect report is at http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/dr_338.htm

Comment: @EricPostpischil An indeterminate value may be a trap representation, and then using it would abort the execution. Were you thinking of unspecified values?

Comment: @DanielFischer In his first comment, Eric argued that modern architectures do not have trap representations, and therefore “either an unspecified value or a trap representation” simplifies into “an unspecified value”. This is a valid argument, although compilers will still bite you (what I said in my first comment). I expanded on the subject in a blog post: http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2013/03/13/indeterminate-undefined (password: indeterminate, feel free to leave any remarks before I publish it)

Comment: @PascalCuoq Interesting read, thanks. I must admit that my legalese is not strong enough to know whether the absence of trap representations means that the value of an uninitialised object with automatic storage duration is not indeterminate in the sense that using it makes UB.

Answer (score 0):

`And, how does C initialize pointers?`

C doesn't, you do it.

`As far as I know, if a pointer is not initialized, it would have value Null which is equal to 0, correct?`

Wrong. If it's not initialized it has no defined values. It will be garbage. Printing uninitialized variables will result in garbage which is why you can't anticipate the output.

`Why in the first output, the i was initialized?`

It wasn't, it just happened to be pointing to 0.

Side note: you should be printing with `%p` when you're printing pointers.

Answer (score 0):

C only automatically initializes `static` and global variables (globals are declared *outside* of a function) to zero.  *Automatic* variables (that's what your two pointers are called) are not automatically initialized, so you are printing "stack noise" (i.e. whatever values happen to be on the stack when your function was initialized.  The values printed may even change from run to run of your program.  If you want them to be initialized to `NULL` you need to tell the compiler:

```
int *i = NULL;
int *j = NULL;
```